# Package file not updated in archive.canonical.com?

Tags: adobe, canonical

It seems the package file under partner section for archive.canonical.com is not up-to-date

http://archive.canonical.com/dists/precise/partner/binary-amd64/

Foe eg: it has been noticed that a new version of adobe-flashplugin is available from March 15th.

Ref:http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/?C=M;O=D

However, the package header file shows an older version.

Package: adobe-flashplugin
Version: 1:20170214.1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

Ref: http://archive.canonical.com/dists/precise/partner/binary-amd64/

Will it take more time to update the header file ? Whats the normal time period?

Comment: It seems to be in `precise-proposed`, so devs are making it available for testing. For a definite timeline you'll need to ask the devs, all we can tell you is that packages go through `-proposed` first, and if no problems are reported, then go to `-updates`.

Comment: @muru Thanks for the update. Is there any contact of devs?